# MS Word Table - How to achieve this

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am wondering how can I achieve this kind of look, I assume it might be some kind of table

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCQCg.png]

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table with two rows and the number of cells you need horizontally.

Make the top row be the height-difference between the vertical lines.

Either find the 'border painter' in the ribbon, or... right click on top of the table and select 'Properties', then find 'Borders and Shading'. In there set borders to accommodate your needs.